# Is it possible to use MVC 6 in Visual studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project developed in MVC 6 into Visual Studio 2015. I want to configure it in my system. 
My system has Visual Studio 2012.
 I want to know, **Is it possible to run MVC 6 project into Visual Studio 2012?**
I searched a lot but I did not get satisfactory answer.Can anyone guid me regarding this?
When I tried to buil this project in my system, **I got the error i.e. "The Web project 'ABC' requires missing web components to run with Visual Studio."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 (renamed to ASP .NET Core 1.0) includes MVC 6 (renamed to ASP .NET Core 1.0 MVC, with no trailing version number) and it goes well with Visual Studio 2015. If at all possible, you should consider installing Visual Studio 2015.

On one of my laptops, I have VS2012, VS2013, VS2015 and VSCode all sitting happily next to each other. So if you still need VS2012 for some reason, you can always install VS2015 on the same machine.

If you're concerned about cost, you can download VS2015 Community Edition, which is free for individuals, startups and small teams.

I would suggest downloading the latest version from:

- http://get.asp.net

EDIT:
After the RC2 release in May 2016, the get URL now redirects to:

- https://www.microsoft.com/net

There's a download button on this page to get ASP .NET Core, which leads to:

- https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

If you need a more lightweight editor or you want to develop across Windows/Mac/Linux, the new ASP .NET Core also works with the cross-platform VS Code;

- http://code.visualstudio.com

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Shahed, I updated my VS to 2015. And it works fine.